# balance calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in which 5 column

```
accno  valuedate withdra diposits balance paymentaltkey  
1     2015-01-01  25000    0     25000    0  
1     2015-01-02  500      0      25500     1  
1     2015-01-03   0      1000    24500   2  
1     2015-01-03  2000      0     26500    0  
1     2015-01-04   0      1000     25500    2  
1     2015-01-05  2000      0     27500    1  
1     2015-01-06   4000     0     29500    0
```

Now I need to calculate new balance in which if `paymentaltkey` = 1 then we don't add `withdra` in balance. If `paymentaltkey` = 2 then we don't substract `deposit`.

How to create new balance output like this:

```
accno  withdra diposits balance payme    newbalace
1       25000      0      25000    0       25000
1         500      0      25500    1       25000
1           0   1000      24500    2       25000 
1        2000      0      26500    0       27000
1           0   1000      25500    2       27000
1        2000      0      27500    1       27000
1        4000      0      29500    0       31000
1           0   1000      25500    0       30000
```

Comment: Sameer sawant, your algoritm of calculating `newbalance` doesn't allow to get values, that you have in the example.

Comment: Tag the version of SQL Server of the database you are running this against (`SELECT @@VERSION;` to verify)

Comment: Some kind of `date` or `id`/`order_id` column is required to identify natural order of records.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to have a column that describes the order of the records, otherwise you can't really calculate anything. Then just do a running total with case statement, something like this:

```
select *,
  sum(case when paymentaltkey = 1 then 0 else [withdra] end 
    - case when paymentaltkey = 2 then 0 else [diposits] end) 
         over (partition by [accno] order by yourorderingcolumn) as [newbalace]
from
  yourtable
```

This is for SQL Server 2012+, if you're using older version, just check how to do a running total.